# use paste to generate seq

Tags: r, file, paste

I would need to generate the seq

ROW /t t1 /t t2 /t3 up to 1500 in R

Currently I do

```
writeLines(paste("ROW", paste0("t", 1:1600, collapse="\t")), paste("file",i,sep=""))
```

then theere is not /t between the first element and the next.  I need to add a line to the file with the comman

```
`cat(paste("REGION","chr","1","10000000",sep="\t"), file=paste("file",i,sep=""),append=T,sep="\n"`)
```

To get the /t I used

```
writeLines(paste("ROW", paste0("t", 1:1600, collapse="\t")), paste("file",i,sep=""),sep="\t")
```

the point is that then wehen I add

```
cat(paste("REGION","chr","1","10000000",sep="\t"),file=paste("file",i,sep=""),append=T,sep="\n")
```

there is no newline between both commands

so I need

```
ROW /t t1 /t2 /t3 ...

REGION....
```

Comment: Can you be clear? ROW /t t1 /t t2 /t3 or ROW /t t1 /t2 /t3 .

Comment: No slash before t1? I guess you want that with a slash `ROW /t /t1 /t2...`

Answer (score 0):

Try based on that (edited following your more precise request):

```
cat( "ROW", "\t/t\t", paste( "/t", 1:15, sep = "", collapse="\t" ), "\n\n", file = "a" )
cat( paste( "REGION", "chr", "1", "10000000", sep="\t" ),  "\n", file= "a", append=TRUE )
```

I think this gives you what you want, but in case you really don't want the slash in front of `t1` here change to

```
cat( "ROW", "\t/t\tt1\t", paste( "/t", 2:15, ...
```